# What exactly does `dpkg` remove?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I recently installed Kingsoft Office just for trying it out.When I tried to purge it, I faced some problems. Writer, Presentation etc.. can be opened with commands like `et`, etc.. So, my first trial was to try `sudo apt-get purge et`, but it came up with an error `et is not installed`. I tried `sudo dpkg -P kingsoft-office` because the version in this screen shot says `kingsoft-office`. Even this didn't work.[image: kingsoft office software center photo]

But, running `sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office` worked!!

1. Isn't `apt-get` just a frontend of `dpkg`? What exactly is the difference between them?
2. Why did `sudo apt-get purge kingsoft-office` work and `sudo dpkg -P kingsoft-office` not work?

Answer (score 0):

apt-get resolves dependencies and can delete needless packages -> apt-get autoremove

Comment: I meant the difference in terms of their input. `apt-get` removed `kingsoft-office`, but `dpkg` didn't remove.